# Classes in namespace having .h and .cpp files

Tags: c++, class, syntax

So I am making a my own copy of the Vector STL class. I know it is not practical this is just what I'm doing. I'm using visual studio. Here is my code...

**myVector.h**

```
namespace  CS52 {
    class  Vector {
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Vector &);
    };
}
```

**myVector.cpp**

```
#include "myVector.h"
#include <fstream>

std::ostream& CS52::Vector::operator<<(std::ostream&, CS52::Vector &)
{
    // TODO: insert return statement here
}
```

The error I get is Class "CS52::Vector" has no member "operator<<"
Thanks

Comment: That is because it should be `opertaor<<` (or `CS52::operator<<`) not `CS52::Vector::operator<<`

Comment: `operator<<` is a free function, not a class member

Comment: Thanks for marking

Answer (score 0):

You only declared this operator to be a friend of the class.

This should instead be something like:

```
namespace  CS52 {
    class  Vector {
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Vector &);
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Vector &v);
}
```

And then:

```
namespace  CS52 {
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Vector &v)
    {
       return stream;
    }
}
```